# Docker compose can't connect to mysql with volumes parameters

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, volumes

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
    php:
        build: ./php-fpm
        volumes:
            - ./symfony:/var/www/symfony
            - ./php-fpm/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
#            - ./assets/vocabulary-gc-project.json:/var/www/vocabulary-gc-project.json
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    web:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "8888:80"
        volumes:
            - ./symfony:/var/www/symfony
            - ./nginx/symfony.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        depends_on:
            - php
    myadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        environment:
            - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
            - PMA_HOST=mysql
            - UPLOAD_SIZE=1G
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ./phpmyadmin/uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        ports:
            - "3333:3306"
#        volumes:
#            - "./db:/var/lib/mysql"
```

When I uncomment the last 2 lines for saving my database in the repertory 'db' , I can't connect to mysql but without this 2 lines everything is fine.

How can I save my database ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check it:

```
mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_general_ci --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database_name
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: user_password
```

It's work on my all projects.

Comment: When I use your code, I have the following errors : ``mysqli_real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution``

Comment: @wehtam How you connect to database?

Comment: @wehtam Could you please check the ports

Comment: I connect to database with phpmyadmin with  root/password.

Comment: and for the ports everhing is ok when i haven't "volumes" parameters, I can connect to my database

Comment: @wehtam Check the permission db directory.

Comment: if need you can remove db directory and the run your build

Comment: same result with chmod 777 on my folder or with deleting folder

Comment: Could you provide config with connection settings